# SDK project format: Include all dirs and subdirs starting with '.'

Tags: visual-studio-2017, csproj

We use directories within Visual Studio projects to organize code that belongs functionally together and code that lives in a separate namespace.

We have the convention to prepend "." to the directory name if the directory "opens up" a new namespace. This is convenient because these directories are listed first. Afterwards the directories without the "." prefix get listed next to the code files which just lay around. ReSharper is ok with the prefix "." in the sense, that it can propose the correct namespace - should it be wrong.

Now we are putting some effort into moving to the new, lean SDK project format. This includes all files it finds into the project but unfortunately it skips all directories starting with "." which is reasonable (the .vs directory really doesn't make sense to be included into the project).

I can now add all our "."-prefixed directories by hand which is kind of against the concept of the lean project format (it turns out even if I make an "include in project" on a directory in Visual Studio the project file contains a `<Compile Include="..." />` for every single file the directory exists so files added to the directory afterwards will not get included in the project automatically).

Is there a way to provide a pattern instead similar to `<Compile Include="**\.*\" />` to include all directories starting with "." in any hierarchical directory depth? Is there any other, better approach?

We experimented also with other characters instead of ".", but ReSharper cannot cope with anything else than the dot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following three lines did the trick for me:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Compile Include="Sources\**\.*\**\*.cs" />
</ItemGroup>
```